# sympy не все решения уравнения

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Есть код следующего типа:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> a = simplify('2**x-2*x')
>>> solve(a)
[1]
```

Но в этом уравнении 2 корня: 1 и 2. Почему sympy выводит один?

Используется Python 3.5

Comment: Положительное или отрицательное. Целое или с плавающей точкой. Каково "x"?

Comment: scipy.optimize.fsolve()

Comment: [wolframalpha больше решений показывает](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2**x-2*x)

Comment: Реальных все равно 2

Answer (score 0):

`solve()` is not able to reliably solve *any* type of algebraic equations, but only some of them.

From [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations):

> Currently supported:
>         -  polynomial
>         -  transcendental
>         -  piecewise combinations of the above
>         -  systems of linear and polynomial equations
>         -  systems containing relational expressions

As you may see, your equation don't belong to supported (because of the *exponential* part `2**x`).